# Math accent at line start in align causes error

Tags: xetex, align, latex-base, ulem

The following code no longer works after the LaTeX2e 2019-10-01 kernel update (error occurs using XeLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,ulem,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hat{a}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The error message reads:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \hat allowed only in math mode.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: You need to load `unicode-math`, not `fontspec`.

Comment: @Mico That’s mainly due to `no-math` being issued for `fontspec`. If I call `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}\usepackage{ulem,amsmath}`, the error would go away too. But the problem is that I want TFM-based math fonts, not OpenType math fonts.

Comment: The problem seems to  actually be with`ulem`. If I delete it or replace it with `soulutf8`, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** (January 2020)

`ulem` has been updated so that this fix is no longer needed.

---

`ulem` has an unfortunate definition of `\MakeRobust` this has been reported but the package is not updated yet. Meanwhile you can restore the original version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\savedMakeRobust\MakeRobust
\usepackage{ulem}
\let\MakeRobust\savedMakeRobust
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hat{a}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Guess I take another try to raise this with Donald, otherwise I fear we need to play the maintainer's clause card and update ulem on CTAN

Comment: This is now been corrected in ulem, so there is no need for the workaround any longer.